# Automatic generation of Require dependencies from Node-modules

Tags: requirejs

In the data-main require js file, we write like this:
paths: {
  jquery: 'lib/jquery',
  underscore: 'lib/underscore'
}

What I did was manually download the row JS library files and make "lib" folder and move the file into the folder and change the file name if necessary.

I use Nodejs for server, and I am wondering if there's any tool to create these client-side Require path files automatically from the installed Node-Modules. Browserify does a similar job if I don't user Require (creating one JS file, and call it in the other browser JS files.) But it seems like Browserify cannot be used as a path in Require.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution (to browserify, with which I'm not familiar) is to use [bower](http://bower.io/) for managing client side libraries. It is similar to node/npm, but is geared towards browser libraries.

It will not copy or rename libraries, because that step isn't necessary. Instead the libraries will be placed in a directory called `bower_components`. The [`paths` config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths) would look like

```
paths: {
  jquery: "../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery", 
  bootstrap: "../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap",
  ...
}
```

(the actual number of `..` in the path depends on values of other requirejs options).

In development, when all dependencies are loaded asynchronously as separate files they will be loaded from `bower_components` and requirejs optimizer will find them there when generating the optimized single source.

Adding the dependency paths to the config file can be half-automated with grunt plugin [grunt-bower-requirejs](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-bower-requirejs). The idea is that after a library is installed using `bower install LIBRARY` it's path can be added with `grunt bower`.

Comment: Thank you! Probably it's time to try Grunt/Bower..:)